# Python telegram bot: how to extract information from inline keyboard clicks?

Tags: python, telegram, inline, fsm, aiogram

I am trying to make a telegram bot with python and the first big chunk of the job is to make a questionnaire to collect specific information from a user. The first question (about activity type) will be presented as inline buttons and after that simple question-answer style questions will follow.
So it is like:
Stage 1 - choose activity
Stage 2 - provide full name
Stage 3 - provide phone number
Stage 4 - see the information you provided in one piece

I can easily make the whole thing in the question-answer style using FSM, but I ran into trouble trying to add buttons.

As I see it, my problems start when the user clicks on a button but:

1. No information is added into my reg_state class where I store the sates and use that informaiton to move from one state to another
2. The next step tries to grab the information from a message sent by a user, but in this case a user clicks a button and I do not know how to properly reflect that in the code.

When I run it, during stage 1 I get the buttons and click on them, but then I have also to type in the answer to proceed to stage 2. Then it works as intended.
I want to make changes that would allow the following scenario: a user clicks on a button (stage 1), his answer from that button is saved as an answer and then the bot asks him about his or her full name (stage 2).

My first time posting here, sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I will gladly elaborate.

Here is my code that I have so far:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, executor
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from API_KEY_1196494 import API_KEY

# making a class for a state to move from one state to another later and tie commands to a current state
class reg_state (StatesGroup):
    activity = State()
    full_name = State()
    phone = State()

# button names content
button1_text = 'Activity 1'
button2_text = 'Activity 2'

# buttons
button1 = InlineKeyboardButton (text = button1_text, callback_data='activity1')
button2 = InlineKeyboardButton (text = button2_text, callback_data='activity2')

#keyboard
keyboard_inline = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(button1).add(button2)

# answers
enter_your_name_details = 'Enter your full name'
enter_your_phone = "Enter your phone number"

bot = Bot(API_KEY)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage = storage)


# job initiated, asking to choose activity
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def activity_reg (message: types.Message):
    user_name_greeting = message.from_user.first_name
    await message.answer (text = f"{user_name_greeting}, Which activity do you want to choose?", reply_markup=keyboard_inline)
        

# reading button info
async def inline_buttons_handler(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    match call.data:
        case 'activity1':
            await call.message.answer (f"You chose {button1_text}")
            await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)
            await reg_state.activity.set()
        case 'activity2':
            await call.message.answer (f"You chose {button2_text}")
            await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)
            await reg_state.activity.set()
    await call.answer()

@dp.callback_query_handler(inline_buttons_handler)

    

# grabbing the info about activity provided by the user and asking for name
@dp.message_handler(state=reg_state.activity)
async def grab_activity (message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(activity = message.text)
    await message.answer (enter_your_name_details)
    await reg_state.full_name.set()

# grabbing the info about the user's name and asking for phone
@dp.message_handler(state=reg_state.full_name)
async def grab_full_name (message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(full_name = message.text)
    await message.answer (enter_your_phone)
    await reg_state.phone.set()

# grabbing user's phone info and wrapping it up
@dp.message_handler (state = reg_state.phone)
async def grab_phone (message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data (phone = message.text)
    data_full = await state.get_data()
    await message.answer(f"Activity: {data_full['activity']}'\n"
                         f"Full name: {data_full['full_name']}\n"
                         f"Phone: {data_full['phone']}")
    await state.finish()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

I tried playing with reg_state.activity.set() command. Firstly, I noticed that when I had it in the activity_reg function, the thing wouldn't run at all, so I moved it to the callbackQuery handler. Still it doesn't save anything.
I tried changing it to be equal to the result of the click, but it seems either I am doing it wrong/don't know proper commands or the solution is elsewehre.

Answer (score 0):

you cant get data from inline keyboard button by

```
query = callback_query
query.message.text
```